# Did Plato practice pankration?

Tags: ancient-greece, greece, plato

At what level, if at all did Plato practice the martial art of [pankration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pankration) and what direct evidence do we have for believing so?

Pankration is a Greek martial art; a sort of bare knuckles MMA in that there were essentially no rules (eye gouging and biting are forbidden). There are many accounts online from martial art adjacent sources of Plato having been a Pankration practitioner, even somewhat of a champion.

These accounts vary from him having simply practiced the sport; to having been an Olympian. Is this simply a myth? Or is there direct evidence supporting the claim?

Comment: Please cite examples "There are many accounts online . . . "  Are these from reputable sources?

Comment: Aside; my Greek is rusty, "Was Plato a Pankrator?"

Comment: I'm picturing a really rockin' bit of mashup fiction. "Dialogues and Demons". It practically writes itself.

Comment: Could you provide a citation to at least one of these sources? You don't need the absolute best source - one of the things we can do here is help find scholarly and/or more reliable sources for something you already have a source for. As it stands, your question seems to be purely speculative. Right now, the question is equivalent to asking whether Theodore Roosevelt played basketball or whether Queen Elizabeth II plays Dungeons & Dragons. Maybe yes, maybe no, but no particular reason why researching it would be interesting or relevant.

Comment: Plato was a wrestler - Plato is believed to be his ring name, although other origins have been proposed. I don't believe pankration was the same thing as wrestling, but stand to be corrected. Where exactly did you hear that Plato did pankration?

Comment: @MCW no........